# Implementing a map with unknown key type

Tags: c++, matrix

I'm a physicist working on a code that needs to construct and then cache a number of matrices of different type. The matrices then need to be retrievable, given a set of information that uniquely specifies them (a 'key'). I'm trying to find a flexible way of doing this.

My current approach involves bundling together all the 'key' information into a single class:

```
class FilterKey{
    public:
        FilterKey(const char type, const X key1, const Y* key2...);
         ~FilterKey();
        bool operator==(const FilterKey& rhs) const;
    private:
        char type; X mKey1; Y* mpKey2;
  }
```

User code passes these to an interface class called "MatrixDirectory", instantiated as a global variable (but *not* a singleton) that stores a map between types and caches:

```
//MatrixDirectory.hpp
class MatrixDirectory : private NonCopyable{
    public:
        void Clear(); //Calls destructors.
        void Filter(std::vector<double>& U, const FilterKey& key);
    private:
        std::map<char types, FilterCache* caches> mpFilterCaches;
};
```

When MatrixDirectory::Filter encounters a new char type it calls the FilterCacheFactory, which constructs the appropriate derived class from FilterCache based on the char:

```
//FilterCacheFactory.cpp
namespace FilterCacheFactory{
    FilterCache* MakeFilterCache(char type) {
        if '1'==type return new OneDFilterCache();
        else if 'S'==type return new S2FilterCache();
        else if 'B'==type return new B2FilterCache();
        else REQUIRE(False, "Invalid filter type '" << type << "'!");
    }
}
```

and inserts the result into the map. The actual FilterCaches then manage the matrices and perform whatever filtering is necessary, given a FilterKey.

This, or approximately this, I think will work. But I'm a bit concerned about having to be so explicit about FilterKey. It would be better if MatrixDirectory could store also FilterCaches that are keyed on different types. I guess I could do this with variadic templates but I don't want to have to directly #include everything. Is there another way?

Comment: Use `boost::variant` or `boost::any`

Comment: @JordanMelo this is, unfortunately, not possible since I do not have sufficient influence over the project to include new libraries